# Why does the game lag when I load an image and when I display pygame shapes?

Tags: python, image, pygame, shapes, lag

Just out of curiosity, why does a game lag when I load an image as well as display pygame shapes for example rectangles, circles and ellipses. I have this code where you shoot the ghosts that fall down (I'm still working on the shooting part). I made the cannon out of pygame shapes. But when I run it the images of the ghosts are prefect but the images of the cannons lag and disappears and reappear and so on. Is there any way to stop this lag or disappear and reappear thing? I'm running python 2.6 with windows vista.

```
import pygame, sys, random, math
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
WINDOWWIDTH = 600
FPS = 30
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
TEXTCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE    = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
BROWN    = (139,  69,  19)
DARKGRAY = (128, 128, 128)
BGCOLOR = WHITE

GHOSTSPEED = 10
GHOSTSIZE = 20
ADDNEWGHOSTRATE = 8

def keyToPlayAgain():
    while True:
        for event in event.type.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                return

def getAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # Return value is 0 for right, 90 for up, 180 for left, and 270 for down (and all values between 0 and 360)
    rise = y1 - y2
    run = x1 - x2
    angle = math.atan2(run, rise) # get the angle in radians
    angle = angle * (180 / math.pi) # convert to degrees
    angle = (angle + 90) % 360 # adjust for a right-facing sprite
    return angle

def Text(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 2, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWHEIGHT, WINDOWWIDTH))
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('s.icon'))
pygame.display.set_caption('Ghost Invasion Pacfighters')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')

ghostImage = pygame.image.load('ghosts.png')
dotImage = pygame.image.load('dot.png')
dotRect = dotImage.get_rect()
creditsPage = pygame.image.load('credits.png')
titlePage = pygame.image.load('title.png')

pygame.time.wait(10000)
DISPLAYSURF.blit(creditsPage, (0, 0))
pygame.time.wait(10000)
DISPLAYSURF.blit(titlePage, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

cannonSurf = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
cannonSurf.fill(BGCOLOR)
pygame.draw.circle(cannonSurf, DARKGRAY, (20, 50), 20) 
pygame.draw.circle(cannonSurf, DARKGRAY, (80, 50), 20) 
pygame.draw.rect(cannonSurf, DARKGRAY, (20, 30, 60, 40)) 
pygame.draw.circle(cannonSurf, BLACK, (80, 50), 15) 
pygame.draw.circle(cannonSurf, BLACK, (80, 50), 20, 1) 
pygame.draw.circle(cannonSurf, BROWN, (30, 70), 20) 
pygame.draw.circle(cannonSurf, BLACK, (30, 70), 20, 1) 

health = 100
score = 0
topScore = 0
while True:
    ghosts = []
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    ghostAddCounter = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_x:
                    bombs()
                elif event.type == ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for cannonx, cannony in ((100, 500), (500, 500)):

            degrees = getAngle(cannonx, cannony, mousex, mousey)

            rotatedSurf = pygame.transform.rotate(cannonSurf, degrees)
            rotatedRect = rotatedSurf.get_rect()
            rotatedRect.center = (cannonx, cannony)
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf, rotatedRect)

            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (mousex - 10, mousey), (mousex + 10, mousey))
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (mousex, mousey - 10), (mousex, mousey + 10))

            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, 0, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 1)

            pygame.display.update()

        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            ghostAddCounter += 1
        if ghostAddCounter == ADDNEWGHOSTRATE:
            ghostAddCounter = 0
            newGhost = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-GHOSTSIZE), 0 - GHOSTSIZE, GHOSTSIZE, GHOSTSIZE),
                        'speed': (GHOSTSIZE),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(ghostImage, (GHOSTSIZE, GHOSTSIZE)),
                        }

            ghosts.append(newGhost)

        for s in ghosts:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                s['rect'].move_ip(0, s['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                s['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                s['rect'].move_ip(0, -1)

        for s in ghosts[:]:
            if s['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                health -= 10

        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

        Text('Score: %s' % (score), font, DISPLAYSURF, 10, 0)
        Text('Top score: %s' % (topScore), font, DISPLAYSURF, 10, 40)
        Text('Health: %s' % (health), font, DISPLAYSURF, 10, 560)

        for s in ghosts:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(s['surface'], s['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()

    Text('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    pygame.display.update()
    keyToPlayAgain()
    pygame.display.update()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: Your best bet to resolve it will be to start by breaking it down, so create a second project in which you will only add the cannon. If that works, then gradually add rest of the stuff and see at which point it will start acting up. This will allow you to easily pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: Which part of your code do you think is lagging? You say "when I load an image", but you're pre-loading all of your images (which is good), not doing it inside the game loop at all, so I can't see how it could make the game lag, unless you're talking about startup time being too long or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you draw your cannons, update the display, then clear the display, draw the other stuff, and update the display again. You basically never see the falling ghosts and the cannons at the same time. This results in the flickering you see.

So remove `pygame.display.update()` from this `for` loop

```
    for cannonx, cannony in ((100, 500), (500, 500)):
        ...
        pygame.display.update()
```

and put `DISPLAYSURF.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)` at the top of your `while` loop (or at least before you draw anything):

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...

    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

    for cannonx, cannony in ((100, 500), (500, 500)):
        ...
```

It's best to clear the background *once at the start* of your code that draws everything, and call `pygame.display.update()` *once at the end* of that drawing code.